# How to detect real face using flutter

Tags: flutter, tensorflow, dart, google-mlkit

I want to make an attendance system where users can attend with the camera.

I am using

> tflite_flutter.
> google_ml_kit

It works perfectly but if I take a picture and show it in front of the camera it also works. I need to stop that. How can I detect pictures or videos or real faces in flutter?

Comment: This might help https://youtu.be/W1pToZhm3S8

Comment: Thanks  but it is not working

Answer (score 2):

In order to detect if faces are real or not, it may not be very hard to use a normal camera as the input for the system, as it may not provides enough data to prevent picture or video to be used to trick the system, That's why many face recoqnition systems uses some kind of extra sensors to ensure the security of the system.

For your case of attendance system, it may be better to get another external device/sensor that is able to feed the required data to prevent fake data to the system maybe via something like BLE.